# boot2docker access elasticsearch on localhost

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker, docker-compose

I'm running *boot2docker* on a Mac for my development. I built a Docker image containing a *Jetty* server which is connecting to *elasticsearch* at `localhost` together with Redis and MySQL.

I'm running *docker-compose* with a host bridge configuration which looks like the following:

```
 api:
  image: api
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
   JETTY_ENVIRONMENT: dev
  net: "host"
```

What I want is accessing *elasticsearch* which I installed on my Mac via `localhost:9200`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this? I know we're not supposed to answer with links, but I thought it'd be OK since it's a [link to a boot2docker file on Github.](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md#port-forwarding)

Comment: It seems to work in case of accessing docker container as Localhost , However I want to access my host machine as localhost inside docker containers ,   SOLVED it by creating simple HA proxy docker container